# Can you find the secret word in the hat?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

One hat contains a word, hidden in the design.
Can you find it?
If you're paying attention and use your smarts a lil, you just might see it...

Comment: Hi Raven Dreamer... I'm the Art Director at StackExchange that designed and created hat dash, skyrim vs mw3, and am also an avid gamer -  http://stackexchange.com/about/team scroll to bottom. :)

Comment: I just rolled it your "delete request" edit back.  If you want to delete your question, you should be able to since there are no upvoted answers.  Otherwise you could flag it for mod attention to get it deleted.  It's just ugly if you edit it that way.

Comment: Nice work on the snowy "theme", man.

Comment: @JeffMercado thanks, had no idea that's how it worked. Not noticeable for me... but good to know.

Comment: Can we get a hint or something since HD is almost over?

Answer (score 2):

There're multiple hats with obvious words on them:

- Lump of Coal contains the word `COAL`
- Egg bacon and spam contains the word `SNAP`
- The rep cap contains the word `REP`

Comment: I figured those weren't ... hidden. Can't find Lump of Coal btw.

Comment: @StevenJeuris It's a hidden hat. You get it for downvoting a question.

Comment: It's hidden?  It's the first hat I got... oops.

Answer (score 1):

It's for sure the brain. But what the word says exactly, I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: `ZERG TRIPPE` ?

Comment: you guys are getting there...

Comment: Was never able to read graffiti, and this doesn't look any more readable. :)

Comment: PCE is in the brain... not sure if there's letters I can't see or if it's just an awkward spelling of Peace though.

Answer (score 1):

I think the brain contains the word `PC`. I'm guessing Sean is a PC elitist :)

Comment: you're pretty close... but I'm a mac user. I'm artsy... and have a background in graffiti... ;)